# Internal expectation failed when uploading to an Imgur album

Tags: imgur

I'm using the Imgur v3 API to create albums and upload images to them. The album creation is done by POSTing to `https://api.imgur.com/3/album` and this part succeeds with the below response:

```js
{"id"=>"6RVstQK", "deletehash"=>"ClSxMKYLa5sI6hL"}
```

However when I do the upload to the `https://api.imgur.com/3/upload` endpoint and provide the `album` as a POST variable with the `id` returned after album creation (as per https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139), I get the following response:

```js
{
   "status"=>417,
   "success""=>false",
   "data""=>"{
      "error""=>""Internal expectation failed",
      "request""=>""/3/upload",
      "method""=>""POST"
   }
}
```

Standard image uploads are working fine. It's just when I try and upload to an album I get this `Internal expectation failed` error back from the API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still having this issue, but I just encountered this problem using the `imgurpython` library.

The problem was that the method `upload_from_path()` had the `anon` parameter default to `True`:

```
    def upload_from_path(self, path, config=None, anon=True):
```

I needed to set `anon` to `False` so that it would include the bearar token in the header in `def prepare_headers(self, force_anon=False)`.

I have come to the conclusion that status `417 Internal expectation failed` indicates that you do not have permission to write to the album, so double check you are sending the correct bearer token in your header.

Comment: Thanks, I actually found that uploading to `https://api.imgur.com/3/image` rather than `https://api.imgur.com/3/upload` fixed it.